# how to login admin by using ip address

Tags: login

I had auto scaling the server, now I want to access the origin server admin by IP Address
For example , http://123.234.56.101/wp-login.php
but when I input the Username and password , it force to https and return an error:
**Error: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.**
how could I use the server IP login to the dashboard directly?

Comment: You probably need to put a hack in wp-config to spot when you're using the IP address and set WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to be `https://<IP_ADDRESS>/` so that the blog things that everything is OK and doesn't try to redirect you. Possibly COOKIE_DOMAIN too. I have done this before but I no longer have access to that server to find the exact code and post it as an answer. And it'd be better to set up a domain name for this though, and ideally get a free SSL cert for that domain name too so you can do all of this over HTTPS.

Comment: why do you need to do this? What's the context behind this? You can always make the site respond to a domain even if that domains DNS isn't live, then update your machines local hosts file, so you don't have to use an IP. This is also true if the IP is for an internal server such as an office machine used as a staging server. Context is also important because you may be given an answer that's correct but can't be used in your situation

Comment: the site domains was already live, because the auto scaling, all the change in live site admin can not be executed, so I make the mirror of the origin server, now I want to login to the mirror server, only through the IP address can login mirror server correctly , domain login will take me to live site , not the mirror server.

Comment: Oh I thought you said you were logging into the live origin server? If this is a mirror with a separate database then change the blog URL and site URL in the mirror database to be the IP address, then it should all just work.

Comment: I don’t understand the change in live site admin cannot be executed because of the auto scaling. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I mean when I login the live admin, anything what I do (even upload a new post)will be reset after few minute, so I can not do anything in the live admin. Please tell me how to change the blog URL and site URL in the mirror database to be the IP address

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/